# quintic solution to noncommutative polynomial

Tags: polynomials, noncommutative-algebra, quintics

So, we know there are generally no solutions to an arbitrary quintic polynomial (EDIT from comments: Of course, I mean you can't write the roots using radicals, not that the roots don't exist). I don't know Galois theory, so I understand this result by thinking about permutations of roots and coefficients ([this video is awesome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSHv9Elk1MU&t=657s)!). To me it seems to boil down to the fact that when you write a polynomial in terms of coefficients and roots:

$$x^5 + ax^4 + bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)(x-x_5)$$

There is a natural ordering of coefficients, but not a natural ordering of the roots (you can permute the $x_i$'s and get the same set of coefficients, but if you switch the coefficients, you'll change the roots). That's from the basic property of commutativity of multiplication.

So...what if you considered a "noncommutative polynomial", in which

$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\neq (x-x_2)(x-x_1)$$

Since this would imply a natural order to the roots (and switching the roots would result in a different set of coefficients), does that mean these higher order polynomials *would* have solutions? Is there any work in this area?

I can see some simple and immediate implications of these things - for example, you need more coefficients, since polynomials can be written like

$$x^2+ax+xb+c=0$$

(even worse, I guess it's possible you have to write $x^2=dx^2+xex+x^2f$ or something.)

Comment: It's not that there are no solutions, rather the solutions can't be written using radicals.  Every nonconstant polynomial over the complex numbers has roots: that's the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.  From this point of view, going to a non-commutative structure (division ring?) could only make things worse, not better.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: yes yes, thanks for the clarification, of course the roots EXIST, I'm talking about the formula used to find them cannot be written with radicals. But I'm actually going to write answer I thought about here anyway, in case people care in the way I was thinking about it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez A "natural" order of the coefficients is just saying that just by looking at the polynomial you can identify which coefficients are which - "a" is "the coefficient of the $x^4$ term". And I think it's actually very important that the roots do not have the same property, because if they did it would be trivial to find a map coeff -> roots. I would recommend watching the video I attached, or further clarification about why you think that's not the important feature of the problem here.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: You have a very fair point here, in regards to the "natural ordering" not being a complete explanation of this problem, as something else much change once you hit order 5. However, since the proof I'm talking about *does* look at the various ways of ordering the roots (by commutators of permutations), I still think some of the essence of the problem may be contained in a more careful presentation of my original statement.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I just thought of the answer...my intuition was right, it's far easier to find the roots of a "noncommutative polynomial" (although I still don't know how generally interesting this concept is). Just think about writing it out for the quadratic:

$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=x^2-x x_2 - x_1 x + x_1 x_2=0$$

Now compare this to the most general form of a quadratic:

$$Ax^2 + xBx + x^2 C + Dx + xE + F =0$$

And we can read off the roots from the coefficient list!

$$A=1,~E=-x_2,~D=-x_1,~F=x_1x_2$$

Of course, there's some ambiguity here, since $C=1$ is also fine, and when I write "1" I mean "the noncommutative unit" I guess.

I would still like to hear if anyone finds anything else kind of interesting about this, but this is basically the answer I was looking for - I just didn't think too carefully about it before posting!

Comment: I think you need to specify what noncommutative algebraic structure you're working with.  You can't just assume it satisfies the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: Even though the structure (presumably a ring) is noncommutative, there are still elements that do commute with each other.  For example, anything commutes with itself;  if there's a multiplicative identity it will commute with everything, and so will integer multiples of it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael for sure, I am not quite sure what the algebraic structure is, and part of my question is asking about the reasonableness of this whole line of inquiry. I would like to say "The coefficients and the variable $x$ is part of a noncommutative ring", that is, a ring in which the multiplication operation is not commutative. I think that's all I need right? There might be lots of interesting features of considering what kinds of ideals line in this ring, etc, but I think I don't need any additional structure for the essential argument I am making, right?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thinking more carefully and trying to interpret what you mean - are you saying that matching terms like $-xx_2=xE$ doesn't imply $E=-x_2$? For example, maybe $E$ actually commutes with $x$ (some values of $x$, I guess), so that maybe $E=-x_1$ if $[x_1,x]=0$...but actually I think if $-xx_2=xE$ for all $x$ then $E=-x_2$ is the only solution that works. Anyway, can you clarify if that line of thinking is what you are worried about?

Comment: There are several issues.  One is that the polynomials don't factor as a product of linear terms.  Another is that the matching idea doesn't work because you might have $Dx$ equal to  $xD$ (or perhaps $x D'$ for some $D'$, at least for some values of $x$).

Comment: Some examples to consider: in the ring of $2 \times 2$ real (or complex) matrices, there are no solutions to $$x^2 - \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr} = 0$$ and intinitely many solutions to $$x^2 - \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr} = 0$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I appreciate the examples, and yes they are clear and convincing regarding the naivety of my answer.